# Firebase Push silent push notification HTTP v1

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sending the following request to FCM through their [new HTTP v1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send) or through their [HTTP Legacy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) doesn't produce the silent expected notification.

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-name/messages:send
{
  "message": {
    "apns": {
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "content-available": 1
        },
        "some": "test",
        "and": "more",
        "nested": {
          "content": "with_value"
        }
      },
      "headers": {
        "priority": "5"
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "some": "content"
    },
    "token": "..."
  }
}
```

Neither does it work through Legacy API

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
{
    "to": "...",
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "normal",
    "data": {
        "some-key": "value"
    }
}
```

But if I send the request directly to APNS without FCM layer following code just gets executed properly:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Some title"
    content.body = "Some content"

    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString,
                content: content, trigger: nil)

    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
       if error != nil {
          // Handle any errors.
       }
    }

    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

Additional information:

- Adding `badge` to `apns` updates the badge on the app so the notification is received
- Setting `notification` key creates a notification in notification center
- All my examples receive a success response from FCM
- I've tried many combinations for both calls

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Comment: for legacy Api u should add "notification" tag.
for example:
{
 "to" : ".....",
  "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 },
 "content_available": true,
 "data" : {
  "some-key": "value"
 }
}

Comment: Nope I didn't. I would have like to make it work with new API but never achieved. I ended up using APNs directly